# Need suggestions to clarify the concept of mongoDB to store and retrieve images

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I am new to mongoDB. I was told to use mongoDB to my photo management web app. I am not able to understand mongoDB's basic concept. The documents.

`What is documents in mongoDB?`

```
j = { name : "mongo" };
t = { x : 3 };
```

In mongoDB website they told that the above 2 lines were 2 documents.

But till this time i thought `.txt, .doc .excel... etc.` were documents.(This may be funny, but i am really in need of understanding its concepts!)

How do you represent a txt file for example `example.txt` in mongoDB?

`What is collection?`

`Collection of documents is known as "Collections in mongoDB"`

How many collections i can create?

`All documents were shared in all collections`

Finnaly i come to my part, `How shall i represent images in mongoDB?`

With the help of tutorials i learned to store and retrieve images from mongoDB using java!!

But, without the understanding of mongoDB's concepts i cannot move further!

The blog's and articles about mongoDB is pretty interesting. But still i am not able to understand its basic concepts!!!

Can anyone strike my head with mongoDB!!??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps comparing MongoDB to SQL would help you ...

In SQL queries work against tables, columns & rows in set-based operations. There are pre-defined schema's (and hopefully indexes) to aid the query processor (as well as the querier!)

**SQL Table / Rows**

```
id  | Column1 | Column2
-----------------------
 1  | aaaaa   | Bill
 2  | bbbbb   | Sally
 3  | ccccc   | Kyle
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = 'aaaaa' ORDER BY Column2 DESC
```

This query would return all the columns in the table named **Table1** where the column named **Column1** has a value of *aaaaa* it then will order the results by the value of **Column2** and return the results in descending order to the client.

**MongoDB**

In MongoDB there are no tables, columns or rows ... instead their are **Collections** (these are like tables) and **Documents** inside the Collections (like rows.)

**MongoDB Collection / Documents**

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("497ce96f395f2f052a494fd4"),
 "attribute1" : "aaaaa",
 "attribute2" : "Bill",
 "randomAttribute" : "I am different"
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("497ce96f395f2f052a494fd5"),
 "attribute1" : "bbbbb",
 "attribute2" : "Sally"
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("497ce96f395f2f052a494fd6"),
 "attribute1" : "ccccc",
 "attribute2" : "Kyle"
}
```

However there is no predefined "table structure" or "schema" like a SQL table. For example you can see the second document in this collection has an attribute called *randomAttribute* that none of the other documents have.

This is just fine, it won't affect our queries but does allow for for some very powerful things ...

The data is stored in a format called BSON which is very close to the Javascript JSON standard. You can find out more at http://bson.org/

**MongoDB Query**

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = 'aaaaa' ORDER BY Column2 DESC
```

How would we do this same thing in MongoDB's Shell?

```
> db.collection1.find({attribute1:"aaaaa"}).sort({attribute2:-1});
```

Perhaps you can already see how similar a MongoDB query really is to SQL (while appearing quite different.) I have some posts up on http://learnmongo.com which might help you as well.

Comment: Thanks, did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a document database : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database